# should you create a separate user account for each user of a system or using one for everyone sufficient

Tags: linux, user-management

As I have noticed many times, when there's some Linux system in a company it usually has one user account and everybody that needs to do some changes on the system, then uses that account. So over time, it becomes impossible to understand who did what, and whom to ask about changes on the system.

Is it a good practice to have multiple user account on a system and provide these accounts to actual users, so that you'd be able to see which user changed configs or added new files? Are there, maybe some tools for Linux that make user management easier, like GUI tools? And maybe tools that allow to audit changes in some configurable locations on the system?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

In practice:

- on important systems, very few people should be authorized to make changes, and such changes should be tracked anyway (tickets)
- if each user logs in with personal credentials (even if it is only to `su` to root for the rest of the session) you can:

  - at least know who accessed the system,
  - more importantly, remove someone's access without impacting the others (no need to change the common password(*))

  This means that either you have individual ids+passwords (and then use `su`) or use SSH keys (in which case the root user can accept the individual SSH keys).

(*) I once worked in a project with a single userid for 40 people, and automatic suspension after 3 invalid login attempts. This led to total chaos...

Comment: Accountability is very important.